# Firebase storage Automatic sync with local storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a couple of folders in the fire-base storage, I want to download those folders into local storage (I have a code for that)

Other case if I change the file in those fire-base folder, it should reflect into local storage also. Is there any way to do automatically?

Instead of manually checking the each folder or maintaining the database ([like_this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552408/how-to-observe-firebase-storage-upload-event)) for the track and downloading., Is there any API it will do automatic sync for every changes (Insert or creating new folder or files, updating, deleting).

Here i don't even need live update. Is it ok to check for the update and sync while opening app.

**Update 1:**

I got some silly idea, let me know your thoughts on this. Is there any way to store image file in fire-base NO-SQL DB(like storing it as blob in SQL lite), so that database will get sync run-time, i will also read it from my local database file. I know its an ODD idea.But let me know your comments.

OR

Is there any free service (Like AWS) have the option to storage sync?

**Update 2:**
Even any cloud storage is ok with me (Like Dropbox,share file.etc.,). what i  need is file sync need to happen automatically.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: > Is it ok to check for the update and sync while opening app.

Yes it is, and it's probably the only way you can do it. Just be cautious of a high number of records being stored!

Comment: @ElliotHesp Yes, its ok to check and sync while opening.

Comment: Yes, however my question would be: If you're querying all of the data on app open, why do you need to store it in local storage anyway, as you're making the request each time regardless of what's in there.

Comment: @ElliotHesp Yes i like to check each time to make sure all the folders are up to date with cloud(In case if changed any file in xxx folder that file alone need to reflect)  The reason behind why i am syncing folder local storage to make sure it work even in offline also

Comment: @ElliotHesp can you please check my update1 and let me know your thought